# add Backslash at the end of each line (but not last line of a paragraph) of a file

Tags: perl, unix

I have a file, contains:

aa bb
ccc

aa
bb
abc def
gh

I have to add ' \' at the end of each line, but not the last line of each paragraph: like

aa bb \
ccc

aa \
bb \
abc def \
gh

Comment: can't test right now, but split each paragraph using `\n\n` then for each splitted paragraph, split using `\n` then add the `\\` and join the lines using `\n`. Same goes for the paragraphs list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set Perl to paragraph mode, prepend  `\` to newlines:

```
perl -p00le 's/\n/ \\\n/g'
```

Output:

```
aa bb \
ccc

aa \
bb \
abc def \
gh
```

This takes advantage of some [Perl flags](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html):

> **-00** The special value 00 will cause Perl to slurp files in paragraph mode.
>
> **-l** enables automatic line-ending processing. It has two separate effects. First, it automatically chomps $/ (the input record separator) when used with -n or -p. Second, it assigns $\ (the output record separator) to have the value of octnum so that any print statements will have that separator added back on.

Here is what Deparse makes of it:

```
perl -MO=Deparse -p00le 's/\n/ \\\n/g'
BEGIN { $/ = ""; $\ = "\n\n"; }
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    chomp $_;
    s/\n/ \\\n/g;
}
continue {
    print $_;
}
```